# How can I use Sum for a string function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, substring

An Employee has multiple contract hours, I want to sum the total hours of the contract for each employee, but the data within the column of total contract hours is in this format: 35.00 - Contract hours
When trying to run the below script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   EmpId
  ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS TotalContractHours
  ,SUM(CAST(Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS INT))
  --OR ,SUM(CAST(Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS  decimal(1,1)))

FROM tbl.Employee

GROUP BY 
  EmpID
 ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5)
```

I am getting error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '28.00' to data
>   type int.

I tried to run it without the sum aggregate and it worked, so i think its something to do with the sum and data type that is not converting

what am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: What is the reason you store integers as varchar? Change the type of the column and everything will be OK without using any workarounds

Comment: Cast to `DECMAL(18, 2)` instead, no?

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: What does the xx.yy mean?  Is the yy fractional hours or minutes?

Comment: The yy is minutes. i dont have access nor permission to change the data type. The data type of the column is nvarchar and using a string to pull out the 35.00 from - contract hours would mean that the data type would have to be converted to perform the sum of the hours.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers devs

Comment: The real problem here is storing numbers as strings. Choosing the right datatype is crucial in designing a good database. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 0):

Since the hours is in format xx.yy you have 2 options:

### 1. Take only the integer part and cast as int:

```
SELECT EmpId
  ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,2) AS TotalContractHours
  ,SUM(CAST(Substring(Contract_Hours,1,2) AS INT))
FROM tbl.Employee
GROUP BY 
  EmpID
 ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,2)
```

### 2. Take whole part and cast as decimal:

```
 SELECT EmpId
      ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS TotalContractHours
      ,SUM(CAST(Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
    FROM tbl.Employee
    GROUP BY 
      EmpID
     ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have tried using the data but it seems not to work. i am getting the below error message for the first one: The substring function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: and the below error message for the second one:   The substring function requires 3 argument(s).

Answer (score 0):

The Error is in the Substring. A Substring(1,2) will work

[image]

But, a (1,5) will not. Most likely due to the Decimal. You might have to Double Convert/Cast to Decimal, then, back to Integer

[image]

Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   EmpId
  ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS TotalContractHours
  ,SUM(Convert(int,CAST(Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS decimal(18,2))))
  --OR ,SUM(CAST(Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5) AS  decimal(1,1)))

FROM tbl.Employee

GROUP BY 
  EmpID
 ,Substring(Contract_Hours,1,5)
```

Comment: Please do [**not** post code as screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)

Comment: Updated. Was using to Prove work not as  an Answer. Updated answer Code to Correct Format

Comment: Thanks All. it worked Richard. the only issue now is the duplicates. I added Distinct to the Select statement....                                                                                                               But it is still adding all the duplicate of Contract_Hours by EmpID..                    For example: There are 160 duplicate record of EmpID 1, contract hours 39,  I would get 6240 Summed Hours.  How can i solve this in order for it to just Sum the Contract_Hours without duplicates, so I get the accurate Total of Contract_Hours

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning the value into **numerical** value first. Subsequently convert it in **decimal**. With the following code it should work.

```
SUM(CAST(CAST(Contract_Hours AS decimal(10,2)) AS int))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly are stuck with this terrible design, then I would attempt to wrap up your query to make it as safe as possible, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    EmpId,
    LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5) AS TotalContractHours,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(19,2), LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5)) ELSE 0 END)) AS SummedHours
FROM 
    tbl.Employee
GROUP BY 
    EmpID,
    LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5);
```

How does this work?

We don't need to bother with `SUBSTRING` as you always start at the leftmost position of the string,so `LEFT` is simpler.  `ISNUMERIC` will tell us whether we end up with a number or not, to save us getting an exception by attempting to `CONVERT` something from a string to a number.  So if the leftmost 5 characters are numeric, we `CONVERT` them to a 2dp decimal, then to an `INT`, then `SUM` them.

Comment: Thanks all, it worked Richard. the only issue now is the duplicates. I added Distinct to the Select statement....     SELECT DISTINCT
    EmpId,
    LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5) AS TotalContractHours,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(19,2), LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5)) ELSE 0 END)) AS SummedHours
FROM 
    tbl.Employee
GROUP BY 
    EmpID,
    LEFT(Contract_Hours, 5);

Comment: Thanks All. it worked Richard. the only issue now is the duplicates. I added Distinct to the Select statement....                                                                                                               But it is still adding all the duplicate of Contract_Hours by EmpID..                    For example: There are 160 duplicate record of EmpID 1, contract hours 39,  I would get 6240 Summed Hours.  How can i solve this in order for it to just Sum the Contract_Hours without duplicates, so I get the accurate Total of Contract_Hours